# Source and phrasing of quote on knowledge and toil

Tags: quote-source

I vaguely remember a quote one of my professors used (a long time ago) in one of his lectures about the difficulty of acquiring knowledge. It went along the lines of: *"Toil is the currency used to acquire knowledge/reach wisdom. The gods decided you have to pay in advance/upfront"*.

The lecture was on the topic of natural sciences (physics/mathematics) and/or their history, Charles University in Prague. My assumption is the quote to be have been coming from the European cultural tradition (so could be anything from Ancient Greece to thinkers connected to the Scientific Revolution/Enlightenment), but that is only an assumption (we are talking about ~20 years ago).

Can you help me find the original?